# How to override colmodel with other template

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid colmodel is defined in web application using optional template and properties like

```
{"template": defaultNumberTemplate,
   ,"label":"Price","name":"Price","width":53,
   "index":"Price","hidden":false
  }
```

In some sites colum model needs special customization. For this special template is defined in site js file like

```
var newOrderPriceTemplate = {
    search : false,
    align: "center",
    sortable : false,
    label: "Special price", // overrides colmodel
    viewable : false,
    formatter: "showlink",
    formatoptions: {
        onClick: newOrderClick
    }
};
```

How to apply this template to colmodel ? Is it possible to use special property like `overrideTemplate` in commodel and add

```
  overrideTemplate: newOrderPriceTemplate
```

to colmodel or any other idea ?

ASP.NET MVC4, Razor, Bootstrap 4 are also used with jqrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The templates was introduced as the set of **default values** for properties of `colModel`. Default values can't change the values from `colModel` specified explicitly.

If you want to change, for example, `formatoptions` of all items of `colModel`, which have some specific criteria, then you should enumerate the items of `colModel`, test the criteria and overwrite there to new value.

Comment: `newOrderPriceTemplate` is simple javascript standalone object.  Maybe it is possble to use something like `$.extend( true, colModel[i], newOrderPriceTemplate)` to set values from `newOrderPriceTemplate` object after main template and inline properties are resolved  in colmodel ?

Comment: @Andrus: Yes, you can do this in your code, but such code is definitively not the part, which should use free jqGrid out of the box. You can write the code which better corresponds your requirements and the settings which you plan to use in `newOrderPriceTemplate`.